# How to cache relational query data in parse?

Tags: android, caching, parse-platform

I am wondering if it's possible to save parse objects in cache together with the related objects when doing a relational query. Let's say this is how I would normally query and pin data in cache if I have network.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> books = ParseQuery.getQuery("Book");
books.include("author");
books.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> books, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                 ParseObject.unpinAllInBackground("allBooks", books, new DeleteCallback() {
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        if (e != null) {
                            // There was some error.
                            return;
                        }
                        // Add the latest results for this query to the cache.
                        ParseObject.pinAllInBackground("allBooks", books);
                    }
                });

                for (ParseObject book : books) {
                     String authorName = book.getParseUser("author").getString("name");
                     String bookTitle = book.getString("title");
                 }

            } else {
                Log.d("query error", e.toString());
            }
       })
})
```

And this is how I would load data from the cache initially before I call the query above.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> books = ParseQuery.getQuery("Book");
        books.fromPin("allBooks");
        books.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(List<ParseObject> books, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Log.d("cache results", String.valueOf(books.size()));
                    String authorName = book.getParseUser("author").getString("name");
                    String bookTitle = book.getString("title");
                } else {
                    Log.d("cache error", e.toString());
                }
            }
        });
```

The problem is when I load from cache, the data for the ParseUser author is not pinned. And I get this error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ParseObject has no data for 'name'. Call fetchIfNeeded() to get the data.
```

How do I make sure that the author ParseUser data is also pinned together with the rest of the data? Thanks